# VS2010 project shows external dll are missing

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to embed external software to call the API in VS2010. I included the lib and include path of the external software in to my VS project->Properties->C\C++->General->Additional Include Directories and Properties->Linker->General->Additional Library Directories. I even included the lib files name in Properties->Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies. When I execute the project, I get the error saying one of the dll(whose lib I have included) is missing from the machine. When I copy the same dll to the run time path of the VS project, project works fine but the association with the external project fails. Can you please suggest any solution other than which I posted here. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The include paths and the specified additional libraries are only used by your compiler/linker for building the the program. Since you apparently used dynamic linking the program still needs those libraries but has no idea where to find them.

When you try to run the program, windows will try to load those libraries. The places windows will look for these are described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7d83bc18.aspx).

1. The directory where the executable module for the current process is located.
2. The current directory.
3. The Windows system directory. The GetSystemDirectory function retrieves the path of this directory.
4. The Windows directory. The GetWindowsDirectory function retrieves the path of this directory.
5. The directories listed in the PATH environment variable.

As you can see it first searches the folder from where you execute the program, this is why it worked for you when you placed all the dlls together with the exe in one folder.

If you don't want this you can add the places where the dlls can be found to the PATH environment variable (recomended) or copy them all in the windows/system32 folder since that is another place windows will look for dlls.

Comment: I added the path of the dll to PATH, it worked well Warloxx. Thank you.